# React Native Development on Samsung Dex?

Tags: react-native, samsung-mobile, samsung-dex

With the new Samsung Galaxy phones and the Samsung DeX feature which turns it into a desktop pc, is there any hope to develop React Native apps on Dex? So not for Dex, but writing code, running the commands, and more.

First of all, I know it sounds crazy. But hey, a lot of crazy people out there... And think about it, it makes atleast some sense. It runs some sort of crazy Android version that can run any apk. So testing would be able without using an emulator. Writting code is just, you know, a text editor.

Now yes, things like the command line tools not working are probably what pops in your mind now. But is that really something that could not be fixed?

I know, this "I will use my phone as a desktop computer thing" is still new. But it sure has atleast some potential! Perhaps more and more companies will do the same thing.

So what do you guys think about this? Does it sound too crazy? Or perhaps just stupid? I'd love to hear what you guys think!

Comment: This question suits best to Quora. SO doesn't allow opinion based questions (also broad ones)

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry! Any way to change it?

Comment: Uhm, you don't need to do anything, I've already flagged this question, mods will close it. Just copy your question and post it on Quora. You can also share that question in react native facebook group, they will gladly respond and chat about it.

Comment: @EnieJakiro Okay, sorry once again :)

Comment: don't worry, its fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about React Native, but something you might find interesting is that I'm a PHP Web Developer and I actually do 99% of my coding on my phone with Samsung DeX.

When I get to work in the morning I simply plug my phone into DeX and then start working on the websites I have to do for the day. When I leave at night then I simply unplug my phone and go home.

One of my other friends also do a lot of web development on his Samsung DeX. I even remember him mentioning something about React Native if I'm correct. I however have no knowledge of that. He uses some apps in the Play Store that gives him a terminal and lots of Linux dev stuff. I however use my browser for most of my work. I use online code editors and work directly within my WHM and cPanels and systems most of the time.

I honestly love this and have no plan on stopping. I'm exciting about the upcoming Galaxy S10+ and would love to get that and use that as my main development computer when it comes out.

Samsung DeX is really cool once you get use to it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is not totally simple.

On one hand, "yes", you can develop React Native with the Samsung DeX, if you made it into their Beta program.

In November 2018, Samsung announced that [Linux runs on DeX as part of a Beta program](https://www.linuxondex.com/). This allows React Native and related tools to run on the DeX.

Here are 2 related links giving more info:

- [Hands-on: Linux on DeX finally gives the Samsung mobile desktop system a purpose](https://9to5google.com/2018/11/13/linux-on-dex-samsung-video/)
- [Hands-on with Linux on Samsung DeX for the Samsung Galaxy Note 9](https://www.xda-developers.com/hands-on-linux-on-samsung-dex-samsung-galaxy-note-9/)

  - this one actually mentions running Jetbrains Android Studio

Unfortunately this was only a Beta program, and [as per Ron Liechty of the Samsung Developer Program (1 Feb 2019)](https://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SDK&messageId=361252):

> The Linux on DeX beta was invitation only until Dec 14th 2018.  The
>   Beta is closed now and not open for additional registration yet. We
>   will announce once we have extended our invitation.

Watch that link for updates.

---

So without the invitation only Beta program, the answer is still "no" pending further updates.